# Python copy a list with both reference copy and value copy

Tags: python

I'm trying to create two lists a and b.

and a and b should satisfy those conditions:

```
len(a) == len(b) == 5
a == b
a is not b
a[0] is b[0]
a[1] is not b[1]
a[2] is b[2]
a[3] is not b[3]
a[4] is b[4]
```

I try to use

```
b = copy.deepcopy(a)
```

but it doesn't pass

```
a[1] is not b[1]
and
a[3] is not b[3]
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Will you please give example of 2 lists who fulfill your condition ?

Comment: Your conditions contradict themselves, as soon as deepcopy(), a == b will fail. It would be better to explain why you need this.

Comment: sorry i can't, that's all the information i've been given

Comment: Are you given one of `a` or `b` and required to construct the other, or do you just need any two such lists that work? Why do you need to do this, anyway? Is it a test of your understanding of Python?

Comment: It is part of my assignment with no specific purpose, therefore I don't know how can I achieve this

Comment: I just need any two lists that works

Comment: Well, think about what `a == b` implies about the corresponding elements of `a` and `b`, and try to think of what kind of object you can use for `a[1]` and `b[1]` such that `a[1] == b[1]` but `a[1] is not b[1]`.

Comment: What is your expected result from the two list? What does the two list contain?

Comment: List could contain anything as long as satisfy all the conditions above

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe i think the second one is what i've been asked to do, i tried to change a[1] and a[3] to strings but the same issue still happens. And I tried to manually insert values but it still won't work

Comment: @Blaaaakuu strings are also immutable... And it's not clear what you mean by *"still won't work"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach that will work:

```
a = [0, [1], 2, [3], 4]

b = copy.deepcopy(a)
```

This works because `deepcopy` inserts either:

- For *immutable* objects (like `int` or `str`), a reference to the same object, (shares *equality* **and** *identity*); or
- For *mutable* objects (like `list`), a reference to a (deep) copy of the object (shares *equality* **but not** *identity*);

into the new object.

A demo:

```
>>> from copy import deepcopy
>>> a = [0, [1], 2, [3], 4]
>>> b = deepcopy(a)
>>> print a == b, a is b
True False
>>> for a_i, b_i in zip(a, b):
    print a_i == b_i, a_i is b_i


True True
True False
True True
True False
True True
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer you are looking for but at least it will help you in understanding the concept. The values are the same but elements in indices 1 and 3 differ by reference. Hope this helps.

```
import copy

avalues = [(1,1),(2,4),(3,9),(4,16),(5,25)]
bvalues = [(1,1),(2,4),(3,9),(4,16),(5,25)]
a = [avalues[0],avalues[1],avalues[2],avalues[3],avalues[4]]
b = [avalues[0],bvalues[1],avalues[2],bvalues[3],avalues[4]]

print "len(a) == 5:", len(a) == 5
print "len(a) == len(b):", len(a) == len(b)
print "a == b:", a == b
print "a is not b:", a is not b
print "a[0] is b[0]:", a[0] is b[0]
print "a[1] is not b[1]:", a[1] is not b[1]
print "a[2] is b[2]:", a[2] is b[2]
print "a[3] is not b[3]:", a[3] is not b[3]
print "a[4] is b[4]:", a[4] is b[4]
```

Comment: Although I would rarely recommend using it, a loop with `eval` would simplify your code here!

Comment: @jonrsharpe I agree. The intent here was to explain to Blaaaakuu the concept in a readable way. For production code, I would not write this way.